# Using customised bootstrap framework

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I downloaded a customized bootstrap CSS framework from this link

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/customize.html.

And I got only `bootstrap.css` and `bootstrap.min.css` files.
But as I am using responsive feature, I also need the customised version of `bootstrap.responsive.css`. How do I make the `bootstrap.responsive.css` work according to my new `bootstrap.css`.

PS: I have made 15 span columns and given new width for each.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its all included in the single CSS file

Comment: Oh Yes. I was just trying to copy two files. Thanks .